# why doesn't the move tool of gimp work?

Tags: gimp

This is the most frustrating thing ever! How can it be so hard to accomplish one of the most basic aspects of title design? I've tried everything posted here and nothing is working. All I want to do is move a simple line of text but I've now spent over 30 minutes and still haven't accomplished it.

Answer (score 2):

> All I want to do is move a simple line of text.

There are two ways to move a text box using the Move tool in GIMP.

1. Place the cursor **exactly** over some of the text, then drag it:

[image]

2. Place the cursor **anywhere** in the text box, then drag it while holding <kbd>Shift</kbd>:

[image]

However, if you simply place the cursor in the text box and it is *neither* over the letters themselves *nor* do you hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> while you drag it, then your attempts to move the text box will simply result in the background layer being moved instead:

[image]

As you can see from the above screenshots, you want the tool icon to show a four-headed arrow and not a pointing-hand symbol before you attempt to drag using the mouse.

Comment: You can even invert that behaviour by setting that to "Move active layer" - then you'll have to use Shift to move what you are pointing at. From personal experience and some reports by others, that is much less preferable :)

Comment: This *used* to work but now neither of these work with Gimp 2.10.30. Neither with the move tool, nor with the select tool nor with the move tool!! What a PITA!!!

Answer (score 0):

When the move tool is selected, on the left hand side there should be the "move active layer" option. Make sure it's selected